# Batch Effects that are Close to Collinear with Main Effect

Tags: deseq2, batch-effects

Two years ago, I started working on a project uses both RNAseq and ATACseq. It's supposed to be a simple Healthy Control (HC) vs disease study. The sample collection was done in 2 phases, and it was clear that there was a batch effect that we could adjust for.
However, recently, we received additional metadata. Plotting a PCA plot showed that there was another, larger batch effect that we didn't account for--location of sample donation. There are 4 different locations with the disease samples being from any of the 4, but **ALL** HC came from only one of the locations.

I reran the count data through DESeq2 with this design formula: phase + location + disease. It didn't fuss about collinearity like it often likes to do and then pooped out a big list of DEG in the RNAseq.

I could probably run the DEG through GSEA to see if the results match the disease's previously known signatures for biological validity, but what statistical worries should I have about this design matrix? What justification would I need for this statistical asymmetry? Thanks.